# Iterator for Removing SortedLinkedList

Tags: java, iterator, sortedlist

I found a problem that my iterator cannot remove my data in sorted linked list although my data can be found to remove it. Can I ask for a solution ?

My code

```java
package driver;

import adt.SortedLinkedList;
import entity.Payment;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

    public Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public SortedLinkedList<Payment> payment = new SortedLinkedList<>();

    public void data() {
        payment.add(new Payment("P1001", "Credit Card", "22/6/2022", "Paid", (float) 54.00));
        payment.add(new Payment("P2042", "Online Banking", "10/7/2022", "Paid", (float) 100.50));
        payment.add(new Payment("P3045", "Online Banking", "5/8/2022", "Paid", (float) 30.00));
        payment.add(new Payment("P9001", "Online Banking", "5/8/2022", "Paid", (float) 30.00));

    }

    public void display() {
        Iterator<Payment> iter = payment.getIterator();
        System.out.println("\n+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+");
        System.out.println("| Payment ID | Payment Method | Payment Date | Status | Total Payment ( RM ) |");
        System.out.println("+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+");

        //iterator
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            //capture each return employee object , thus need to declare an employee reference
            Payment pay = iter.next();
            //use the emp object for displaying the result
            System.out.printf("|%-12s|%-16s|%-14s|%-8s|%-22.2f|\n",
                    pay.getP_ID(),
                    pay.getP_Method(),
                    pay.getP_Date(), pay.getP_Status(),
                    pay.getP_Total());

        }
    }

    public void store() {
        Iterator<Payment> iter = payment.getIterator();
        display();

        System.out.println("\nRemove Record Function");
        System.out.println("==============================");
        System.out.printf("Fill the payment ID to remove :  ");
        String paymentID = scan.nextLine();

        //iterator
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            //capture each return employee object , thus need to declare an employee reference
            Payment pay = iter.next();
            if (iter.next().getP_ID().equals(paymentID)) {
                System.out.print("ok");
                iter.remove();

            }

        }

        display();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NewClass newC = new NewClass();
        newC.data();
        newC.store();

    }
}
```

Sorted Linked List Code

```html
package adt;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedListInterface<T> {

    private int numberOfEntries;
    public Node firstNode;

    private class Node {

        private T data;
        private Node next;

        private Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }

        private Node(T data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public SortedLinkedList() {
        firstNode = null;
        numberOfEntries = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);

        Node nodeBefore = null;
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        while (currentNode != null && newEntry.compareTo(currentNode.data) > 0) {
            nodeBefore = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

        if (isEmpty() || (nodeBefore == null)) { // CASE 1: add at beginning
            newNode.next = firstNode;
            firstNode = newNode;
        } else {    // CASE 2: add in the middle or at the end, i.e. after nodeBefore
            newNode.next = currentNode;
            nodeBefore.next = newNode;
        }

        numberOfEntries++;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(T anEntry) {
        if (firstNode == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            //declare two nide references
            Node beforeNode = null;
            Node currentNode = firstNode;

            while (currentNode != null
                    && currentNode.data.compareTo(anEntry) < 0) {
                //update the beforeNode and currentNode
                beforeNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }

            //when target found
            if (currentNode != null
                    && currentNode.data.equals(anEntry)) {

                if (currentNode == firstNode)//remove the first node
                {
                    firstNode = firstNode.next;
                } else {//remove in between
                    beforeNode.next = currentNode.next;
                    currentNode = null;

                    numberOfEntries--;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public final void clear() {
        firstNode = null;
        numberOfEntries = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> getIterator() {
        return new SortedListIterator();
    }

    private class SortedListIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        //private int index =0
        private Node currentNode = firstNode;

        //override two abstrac method from iterator interface
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentNode != null;

        }

        public T next() //return the current node's data
        {
            T currentData = null;

            if (hasNext()) {
                currentData = currentNode.data;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }

            return currentData;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contain(T newEntry) {
        boolean found = false;
        Node tempNode = firstNode;

        while (!found && (tempNode != null)) {
            if (newEntry.compareTo(tempNode.data) <= 0) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                tempNode = tempNode.next;
            }
        }

        if (tempNode != null && tempNode.data.equals(newEntry)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfEntries() {
        return numberOfEntries;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (numberOfEntries == 0);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String outputStr = "";
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            outputStr += currentNode.data + "\n";;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return outputStr;
    }

    public T getEntry(int givenPosition) {
        T result = null;

        if ((givenPosition >= 0) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries)) {
            Node currentNode = firstNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition; ++i) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next;     // advance currentNode to next node
            }
            result = currentNode.data;  // currentNode is pointing to the node at givenPosition
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

And this is my result

[image]

As you can see, the system has scan success equal data  but the data still can not be removed and I found on google it just showed me the way to remove a single data like Payment (1,2,3) and no more new array.

Comment: I don't know what this `SortedLinkedList` is, but normally you would need to use the `remove()` method of the iterator, not the `remove(..)` method of the list. In any case, you need to provide a [mre], which includes the code of that `SortedLinkedList` (assuming it is your own, or identify the library it's from). Also your loop is calling `iter.next()` twice per iteration, so you're skipping items.

Comment: Refer to interface [java.util.ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html). There are many questions (with answers) on how to remove elements from a list while iterating it. Did you search before posting?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  My `SortedLinkedList`  actually code by myself and has been imported here but if i change it as `iter.remove()`, the system show me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at adt.SortedLinkedList.remove(SortedLinkedList.java:12)`  while the system can scan successfully equation.

Comment: That means you didn't implement the `remove()` method on the iterator. But the most likely problem is you calling `iter.next()` twice in each loop iteration. But I repeat, you need to post a [mre], which includes your `SortedLinkedList`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I repost my `SortedLinkedList` code. I use `iter.next()` because I reuse the code in my `display()` as it is successful to run so I think it is reusable here.

Comment: My point is that in the `while` loop in your `store()` method, you should call `iter.next()` **only once**, in the `if` you should use the variable `pay` instead of calling `iter.next()` again. In `display()` you call it only once.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ohh now i got what you mean but is it my wrong concept to use `iter.remove()` to remove data in here?

Comment: `SortedListIterator` does not override [default] method `remove`. Hence when you call `remove` you are calling a method that simply throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. Refer to the source code for interface `java.util.Iterator`. Nonetheless I still think it is better to implement interface `java.util.ListIterator`.